# Alternative ways to prove $\{f:f(0)=\sum_k f(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}})g_n (k)\}$ is dense in $\{f\in C^2 (\mathbb{R}) : f(0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)du\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I want to prove that $$E:=\bigcap_{n\geq 1} \left\{f\in C^2 (\mathbb{R}) :f(0)=\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)\right\}$$ is a dense subset of:
$$F:=\left\{f\in C^2 (\mathbb{R}) : f(0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)\mathsf du\right\}$$

We assume that $$\lim_{n}\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)\mathsf du,$$ where $g_n$ and $g$ are probability density functions.

My first idea was to consider $$f_n (x) = f(x)+\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)\mathsf du.$$ In this case, we would obviously have $\lim_{n} f_n=f$, but the problem is $f_n$ is not necessarily in $E$. I am therefore thinking that there might be other ways to prove density of a subset without resorting to the standard definition with sequences. Any help or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $C^2(\mathbb{R}) = $ twice-continuously differentiable functions? What is the topology on $C^2(\mathbb{R})$? That is to say, how are you defining $\lim f_n = f$?